# Cron does not execute. The scripts works fine

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I have a crontab the compress log files.

In `crontab -e` I have -I'm **root**-:

```
5 3 * * 6 find /toMyLogs -name "access*" -a ! -name '*.bz2' -ctime +7 -exec bzip2 -zv {} \;
35 3 * * 6 find /toMyLogs -name "error*" -a ! -name '*.bz2' -ctime +7 -exec bzip2 -zv {} \;
```

An example of the logs are:

```
$ ls -la /toMyLogs
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root       33317 Jul  2 19:04 error_1.log.2012-07-02
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root       12928 Jul  3 08:55 error_2.log.2012-07-03
```

If I execute the command by hand, this is:

```
find /toMyLogs -name "access*" -a ! -name '*.bz2' -ctime +7 -exec bzip2 -zv {} \;
```

it works, but in cron does not work. I did some mini-test with example files -not the logs- and ran cron. **It worked**. So, cron is definitively running.

Do you have any idea of whats is going on. Permissions or the time?

Comment: Most of the things that could go wrong should result in cron sending you mail with the error message. Is your MTA set up correctly? Try adding a `* * * * * echo hello` cron job and see if you get the mail. If not, fix that first. A cron without mail notification is a crippled cron.

Comment: Apparently it is -I have a very limited control of the servers-, I see the mails in `/usr/mail/root`, even the one with `echo hello`. But I **did not find** the ones of my cron, this is, the executed on saturday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment is set up differently when you run cron. It is quite possible that the PATH used by cron does not find the bzip2 program.

[Reasons why crontab does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)

Comment: I will add the PATH to crontab, as `PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` in my case. Nevertheless, I tested the SAME oneliner with test files and it worked, but is not working with the log files using cron. The oneliner used by hand works fine :/

Comment: So it works when you run it at the command prompt, but not when executed via cron? Then it is either an environment issue or cron is not running. Try putting your commands in a script file and add `set -x` in the beginning of it. That way you should get a mail with the expanded commands when cron runs it.

Comment: Well, I did all your recommendations. Put it in a script, used the PATH, etc. and worked. But I don't know what was the error specifically :/ I guess is a good practice to follow your indications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know roots of the problem. But don't you transfer some long command into separate script it may helps.

**ADD**
I had such problem with `cron` - reason was in mismatch of the absolute and relative paths. But here you got absolute..

Answer (score 0):

You scheduled the scripts for running once a week, every Saturday (6th day of the week) at 3:05 and 3:35.

The syntax looks good. The possible problem can be executing *bzip2*. Make sure your crontab PATH contains a path to the program.